# Django notification on comment submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals, django-comments

I am making use of Django's contrib.comments and want to know the following.

Are there any utils or app out there that can be plugged into an app that sends you a notification when a comment is posted on an item?

I haven't really worked with signals that much, so please be a little bit descriptive.

This is what I came up with.

```
from django.contrib.comments.signals import comment_was_posted
from django.core.mail import send_mail

if "notification" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from notification import models as notification

def comment_notification(request):
    user = request.user
    message = "123"
    notification.send([user], "new comment", {'message': message,}) 

    comment_was_posted.connect(comment_notification)
```

Comment: Dedent the `.connect()` call. As it is, it only gets run if `comment_notification()` gets called.

Comment: Could you please describe in detail how you managed to hook this up? What files did you modify the code snippet you pasted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect `django.contrib.comments.signals.comment_was_posted` to [`notification`](http://github.com/jtauber/django-notification)`.models.send()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to register your `comment_notification` function with `comment_was_posted` signal.

```
from django.contrib.comments.signals import comment_was_posted

if "notification" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from notification import models as notification

    def comment_notification(sender, comment, request):
        user = request.user
        message = "123"
        notification.send([user], "new comment", {'message': message,}) 

    comment_was_posted.connect(comment_notification)
```

Comment: where does this code actually go if I'm using the built-in comment tags to render my forms and list of comments?

Comment: You have to put it somewhere, so the code is initiated, ex put at the bottom of models.py. This way it will be initiated when django validates models during runserver

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an app (pretty sure there'll be something out there) but it is fairly straightforward to roll your own. You can tap the `Comment` model's [`comment_was_posted`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/signals/#comment-was-posted) signal to call a function that will send you an email.

Comment: I added some code to the original post, maybe you can take a quick look to see why it's not working, I have no real dealing with the notification or signals network before.