# How to update value in the table referenced by foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-views

I have comment model that references (foreign key) a post model and there is a boolean field in the post model that tells whether this particular post has any comment or not.

- What I want to do is to update this boolean field of the post whenever a comment is made on that post, for this what do I have to do in the view.
- Also when I show all the posts on a page, I want to show those first which do not have any comment, so that people can comment on them.

How can I effectively do the following two things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`comment_was_posted signal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/signals/#comment-was-posted)  to update the associated `Post` once there is a new comment. See this thread to get the general idea: [Django notification on comment submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804248/django-notification-on-comment-submission)

Although it might be better in this case to create a `count_comments()` method on your `Post` model.

To order and filter your Posts by the number of Comments for a given `Post` check [Django's docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) or this blog post: http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/08/django-aggregation-tutorial/

Comment: Actually I am not using django comments, I have made something similar I needed to do a lot of changes and didn't require all the features provided by django comments hence did not use it... So the point is now since I cannot use comment_was_posted signal what else can I do?? Can't I define something in the comments models, such that when a user posts a comment change can be made in the Post object as referenced by the foreign key

Comment: Well, the alternative approach would be to override the save-method of your custom comments-app. Check this for some general info on this topic: http://www.martin-geber.com/thought/2007/10/29/django-signals-vs-custom-save-method/

Comment: The link that you have given tells me where I can write code for pre and post save but what I want to know how can I refer the parent model in the comments model by making use of the foreign key I have? I hope I have made by question clear?

Comment: Hm ... in the save-method you can refer to your model's fields with 'self'. self.title would refer to the title of your current instance / comment. If your comment class has an FK 'post' you can therefore access the related instance with self.post